# Detecting language and rewriting url

Tags: i18n-l10n, uri

Drupal can automagically detect the language to use when displaying content :

- Based on URL
- Based on User preference
- Based on Browser language.

However, when I request a url like : http://mysite.com/toot/lala, Drupal detects the english language (browser settings), but it doesn't rewrite the url to : http://mysite.com/en/toot/lala

I'm afraid that this behavior will induce Duplicate Contents errors.
Does someone know how to correctly set this redirection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Global Redirect module](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) will help you with that issue.

It has a redirection system specific for language prefixes, preventing content duplication.

Comment: This module offers indeed everything need, and many more. Thanks